# Disable LaTeX interpreting my Source File

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

In my Latex file:

```
\lstinputlisting[caption={Pascal Quellcode HashFunctionsTest.pas}]{../source/HashFunctions.pas}
```

Error:

```
[{
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Extra }, or forgotten $.\n      {$Q-}\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 29,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 29,
    "endColumn": 65536
}
```

My lst style

```
\lstdefinestyle{sourceCodeBlock}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},  
  keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
  commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=true,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  keepspaces=true,                 
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=2,
  morekeywords={*, UNIT, INTERFACE, IMPLEMENTATION, USES, BREAK, WORD, LONGINT}, mathescape=true,
}
```

The source file which causes the issue:

```
  IF (m = 0) THEN BEGIN
    Powers := 1;
  END ELSE BEGIN
    result := x;
    FOR i := 1 TO (m - 1) DO BEGIN
      {$Q-} (* Disable Overflow Checks *)
      result := result * x;
      {$Q+} (* Enable Overflow Checks *)
    END; (* FOR *)
    IF (result = 0) THEN BEGIN
      result := x;
    END; (* IF *)
    Powers := result;
  END; (* IF *)
```

Now obviously my Source Code is wrongly interpreted by LaTeX. How can I disable this?

Comment: it would have been much easier to answer if you had provided an example that demonstrated the issue. not disconnected fragments that can not be run, by default listings never interprets the input; it is read verbatim, it is only because you explicitly enabled special processing for `$`  that it did so here, so removing `mathescape=true` is easier then using `mathescape=false`

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Escaping alltogether worked

```
% List Style for Code Blocks
\lstdefinestyle{sourceCodeBlock}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},  
  keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
  commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=true,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  keepspaces=true,                 
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=2,
  morekeywords={*, UNIT, INTERFACE, IMPLEMENTATION, USES, BREAK, WORD, LONGINT},
  inputencoding=utf8,
  extendedchars=true
  escapeinside={},
  mathescape=false,
  texcl=false
}
```